# Regex for a checkbox to send a form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a form with a checkbox that only submits the form when the checkbox is ticked (when the dog has a collar). If the dog doesn't have a collar (unticked box) it displays the message: "Your dog needs a collar to be boarded.".

I think I need a bracket, quotes, or colon around havecollar (line 5 of code)?

The form current works but it doesn't differentiate between a ticked box or an unticked box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hgsubmit(){
    if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.name.value) == false)
        alert ("Please provide your name.");
    else if (/[havecollar]/.test(document.hgmailer.collar.value) == false)
        alert ("Your dog needs a collar to be boarded.");
    else {
        document.hgmailer.submit();
        alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
    }
}
</script>


<form action="http://www.example.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer" id="hgmailer">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="we [EMAIL REMOVED] .com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="FormMail E-Mail (Prospect Dogs)" />
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
            <td>Your name<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup>:</td>
            <td> 
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>My dog will be wearing a collar that has an attachment point for a lead.</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="collar" value="havecollar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="hgsubmit();" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://example.com/test.htm" />
</form>
```

Comment: remove the brackets, like this (/havecollar/ ...

Comment: You are waaaay over thinking it. There is no need for regex. Just give your checkbox element an id such as `havecollar` and then check `document.getElementById('havecollar').checked`

Comment: Changing it from /[havecollar]/ to /havecollar/ still sends the form even when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: I've added it as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for regex. Just give your checkbox element an id such as havecollar and then check `document.getElementById('havecollar').checked`